# Создание Map из двух List с помощью stream().collect

Tags: потоки-данных, map

Почему не работает представленный ниже код? Если `Double` заменить на `Integer`, то все ОК. Такое впечатление, что `Collectors.toMap` в качестве ключа принимает только `Integer`, любой другой тип не работает...

```
List<Double> list1 = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two");

Map<Double, String> map2 = list1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(list1::get, list2::get));
```

Comment: *Такое впечатление, что Collectors.toMap в качестве ключа принимает только интеджеры* - так и есть, только не Collectors.toMap, а List::get

Comment: Да, точно, переписал в следующем виде, помогло
List<Integer> list0 = Arrays.asList(0, 1);
        List<Double> list1 = Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0);
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("one", "two");

        Map<Double, String> map2 = list0.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(list1::get, list2::get));